# Flutter collapsible SliverAppBar, but without the background for the TabBar

Tags: flutter

The example code in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html shows how to display a collapsible `SliverAppBar` with a `bottom:TabBar`.

The problem is, the moment I add `flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar` to set the background picture for the appbar, the picture bleeds to the tabbar. I **don't** want the tabbar to have any background picture.

I could wrap the tabbar in a container and give it a background color, but then the picture will look cropped at the bottom.

Alternatively, https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe suggests that I use `SliverPersistentHeader` for the tabbar.

The problem is, since there are 2 pinned slivers on top, I can't use `SliverOverlapAbsorber`. I need to show different states based on whether the top slivers are expanded/collapsed.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There's an open issue exactly for this problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25723